# How to retrieve a JWT access token from Azure B2C using `NextAuth.js`

Tags: next.js, azure-ad-b2c, next-auth

my infrastructure is as follows:

- I have a back-end Web API that uses Azure B2C authentication (respectively via JWT tokens)
- I have a front-end app written on Next.js and it uses NextAuth.js to manage the authentication.

Everything seems ok - I can authenticate users in the front-end with the registered identity providers but... I need to call the back-end with an access token from Azure B2C so my requests are authenticated.

What is the correct way of managing this access token? I could not find any information about whether or not I should generate it by myself or there is some mechanism to simplify all this?

There is another question I would like to discuss - is NextAuth.js the correct library for my use case? I mean, there is more documentation and examples for `@azure/msal-react`, it is specialized into this matter, so is it the better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NextAuth.js is a fine library to use for this.

You can put the `accessToken` that AzureB2C gives you for the signed-in user into their session JWT in the `jwt` callback in your NextAuth.js config.

See docs about exactly this use-case here: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback
See another example of it in action here: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-refresh-token-example/blob/57f84dbc50f30233d4ee389c7239212858ecae14/pages/api/auth/%5B...nextauth%5D.js#L67

Once you have it in the session JWT, you can use the `getToken()` method in Next.js API routes, for example, to retrieve the token and make calls with it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this guy's blog. It is very educative. He also uses the same things with you.
https://benjaminwfox.com/blog/tech/how-to-configure-azure-b2c-with-nextjs

Although you should consider this is an older version.