# Access Token Undefined in NextAuth Azure AD B2C - NextJS Pages Typescript

Tags: reactjs, azure, next.js, azure-ad-b2c, next-auth

I've been trying to attach the access token in the session, but I don't get the value for access token.

I'm not sure if I'm doing everything right:

```
import util from "node:util";
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import AzureADB2CProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad-b2c";

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        AzureADB2CProvider({
            tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_TENANT_NAME,
            clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_CLIENT_ID ?? "",
            clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_CLIENT_SECRET ?? "",
            primaryUserFlow: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_PRIMARY_USER_FLOW,
            authorization: {
                params: { scope: "offline_access openid" },
            },
            token: {
                params: { scope: "openid profile user.Read.All email" },
            },

            // Attach UserProfileID into the Session Profile while keeping defaults
            profile(profile) {
                return {
                    id: profile.sub,
                    name: profile.name,
                    email: profile?.emails?.[0],
                    userProfileID: profile?.extension_UserProfileID,
                    image: null,
                };
            },
        }),
    ],
    
    callbacks: {
        async signIn({ profile }) {
            // It's a newly created account when extension_UserProfileID does not exist
            if (profile && !("extension_UserProfileID" in profile)) {
                return "/?newUser=1";
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        },
        async jwt({ token, user, account, profile }) {
            // I should get the value for access token in the account
            console.log("account", account);
            // On JWT Token, Attach id_token from account - which exists only on SignIn
            if (account && user) {
                token.id_token = account.id_token;
                token.userProfileID = user.userProfileID;
            }

            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            // Expose userProfileID unto the Session
            if ("userProfileID" in token) {
                session.user.userProfileID = Number(token.userProfileID);
            }

            // Include the ID Token in the Session
            if ("id_token" in token) {
                session.user.idt = String(token.id_token ?? "");
            }

            // To do: Dynamically load Role based on API
            session.user.role = "ServiceRequest";

            return session;
        },
    },

    logger: {
        error(code, metadata) {
            console.error(code, metadata);
        },
        warn(code) {
            console.warn(code);
        },
        debug(code, metadata) {
            console.debug(code, util.inspect(metadata, true, null, true));
        },
    },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

This is the access token configuration in AD B2C:

[Implicit grant and hybrid flows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRkvs.png)

Then this is I would get in the console in the account:

```
account: {
    provider: 'azure-ad-b2c',
    type: 'oauth',
    providerAccountId: '8e22.......',
    id_token: 'eyJraW.......',
    token_type: 'Bearer',
    not_before: 1705946179,
    id_token_expires_in: 3600,
    profile_info: 'eyJraW.......',
    scope: 'offline_access openid',
    refresh_token: 'eyJraW.......',
    refresh_token_expires_in: 86400
  }
```

I tried everything mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70998902/how-to-retrieve-a-jwt-access-token-from-azure-b2c-using-nextauth-js)

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: To fetch access token in Azure AD B2C, you must call the API. The scope must be like
> `scope=https://xxx.onmicrosoft.com/api/read openid offline_access`. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens)

For ***sample***, Expose an API like below:

[image]

And grant API permission for the API:

[image]

Now pass **scope** as `scope: https://srib2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/15b78f43-ca4f-4cea-8989-4d7f45e9d01c/test.read.all openid offline_access` to get the access token:

I generated **access token** via Postman by using below parameters:

```json
https://b2caadtenant.b2clogin.com/b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_testb2c/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/test.read.all openid offline_access
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/vLf7qqW.png)]

***Modify the code like below to get the access token:***

```js
export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        AzureADB2CProvider({
            tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_TENANT_NAME,
            clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_CLIENT_ID ?? "",
            clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_CLIENT_SECRET ?? "",
            primaryUserFlow: process.env.AZURE_AD_B2C_PRIMARY_USER_FLOW,
            authorization: {
                params: { scope: "offline_access openid" },
            },
            token: {
                params: { scope: "https://b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/test.read.all openid profile user.Read.All email" },
            },
```